# Extract commas from variable

Tags: php

Hey there, I have this variable:

```
<?php $blog_description = get_bloginfo('description'); ?>

$blog_description ='I am a text, I have commas, and periods. And I want the text without them';
```

How can I extract the commas and periods from $blog_description? 
 I want to use it as meta description in my website header.

Comment: you want to split the string by commas?

Comment: What do you mean by extract commas?  Split the string into an array?  Remove them from the string?

Comment: What does `get_bloginfo('description')` return?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$blog_description = str_replace(',', '', get_bloginfo('description'));
```

Or to remove commas and periods:

```
$blog_description = str_replace(array(',','.'), '', get_bloginfo('description'));
```

You can always use preg_replace too:

```
$blog_description = preg_replace('/[,\.]+/', '', get_bloginfo('description'));
```